# Is there any way to implement both side pagination in Flutter using PageView?

Tags: flutter, dart, pagination

I can paginate forward without a problem, but I can't paginate in the opposite direction.
I have pageview with weeks and want to upload new weeks on user's scroll
[image]

Can anyone suggest, provide a link to the source, please?

Comment: You should provide code snippet of what you have done so far for us to understand the issue and could help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PageController` with a large `initialPage`, then take care of the offset in `itemBuilder`

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late PageController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PageController(initialPage: 1000);
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  currentWeek() {
    return DateTime.now().difference(DateTime(DateTime.now().year)).inDays ~/ 7;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: _controller,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            color: Colors.purple,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Week ${currentWeek() + index - 1000}",
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using PageView as a widget you have a property named controller, you can attach a controller and then paginate to any side using nextPage() and previousPage() methods like this:

```
class _MyPageView extends State<MyPageView> {
  late final PageController pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
    );
  }

  _moveNextPage() {
    pageController.nextPage(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.linear);
  }

  _movePreviousPage() {
    pageController.previousPage(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.linear);
  }
}
```